# Why is the total number of installed files as reported by apt different when installing/upgrading a package as aposed to when removing one?

Tags: apt

When performing an update of installed packages, I've noticed that apt will list the total number of files installed as each package is upgraded - however, when then using apt to remove a package that's already installed on the system, the total number of installed files is totally different (in certain cases by thousands). Why is this - does apt use different criteria for listing the total number of installed files when removing a package as aposed to installing/upgrading one?

Comment: Maybe config and data file created by the apt.

Comment: Can you show an example output of this? You might not be removing automatically installed dependencies.

Comment: Some packages get installed because of dependency rules, but they get removed when you later do an `apt autoremove` & clean up your system. There are for some packages, where files get installed but are not erased on removal (eg. `plymouth` screens I think of as wallpapers, but get left behind when you `apt remove` the desktop that caused the install... as removal may cause breakage if you no longer had anything to replace it with) but those files are usually inconsequential (it's like an low-res wallpaper in my example)